# ReactJS with Socket.IO, server emits to client, but client doesn't emit to server

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I am learning Socket.IO, and I am trying to do something very simple, emit some text from server to client upon connection (this works), and emit a signal from client to server (this doesn't work).
This is my client-side code (the ReactJS component)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = io.connect('http://x.x.x.x:xxxx');

class Client extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            String1: 'No text yet',
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        socket.on("message", data => this.setState({ String1: data }));

        { socket.emit('Update', 'test') }
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                String1 is: {this.state.String1}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Client;
```

This is my server code (NodeJS):

```
const server = require('http').createServer() 
const io = require('socket.io')(server) 

io.on('connection', function (socket) { 
        console.log('client connected'); 
        socket.emit('message', 'You are connected'); 
        io.on('Update', function(ttext){     
                console.log('Updated'); 
        }); 
}); 

io.sockets.on("disconnect", () => console.log("Client disconnected")); 

server.listen(3000, function (err) { 
          if (err) throw err 
          console.log('listening on port 3000') 
})
```

Client-side: On browser, I correctly see "No text yet", and it changes to "You are connected" as soon as the client is connected to the server.

However, on server-side, I only see "client connected" on terminal at each client browser refresh, but nothing else, no "Updated" and no "Client disconnected".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to attach the message event handler to the provided `socket` connection object, not to the `io` server instance:

```js
socket.on('Update', function(ttext){     
    console.log('Updated'); 
});
```